Efficient way to find a set of vertex with small enough minimal spanning tree
Given a (connected) positive-weighted graph $G = ([n],E, w)$ -- a graph with $n$ nodes/vertices, and edge set $E$, where the weight of an edge $e\in E$ is given by $w(e)>0$ -- a nonnegative value $v$, and a positive integer $m\in [0,n]$, is there any efficient algorithm to determine (or to find) a set of vertices $S \subset[n]$ satisfying:

$|S|=m$, i.e., the chosen set of vertices contains exactly $m$ vertices.
The subgraph of $S$ in $G$ is connected.
For the set of vertices $S$, its minimal spanning tree in $G$ should have weight-sum no greater than the given bound $v$.

The trivial way to determine this is to check all possible combinations of $m$ nodes in $[n]$. However that will make it very slow!
Inspired by the comment below, I think this following lemma ($G$ be a graph with vertex set $V$, and let $T$ be a  minimum spanning tree of $V$. Let $T_1$ be any subtree of $T$, and let $W$ be the vertex set of $T_1$. Then $T_1$ is also an MST of $G[W]$, the subgraph of $G$ induced by $W$. ) maybe helpful.

It's been a long time I've worked with MST, but isnt there an argument saying you can compute the MST for G and for each candidate set S, if an edge is in S and the MST of G, it has to be in the MST of S?

@Qise Sorry I do not understand your question/comment well. What I mean is: $S\subset [n]$ is a set of nodes. And throughout the question, we do not care explicitly about the MST of $G$. We only care about the MST of $S$. However, edges one choose to construct the MST of $S$ must be in $E$ at the first place.

I was just wondering if finding the MST of G might be useful to find the one of a given S faster. For instance let e*=min_e (w(e)), Per Kruskal's if e* is in G[S] it is in MST(G[S]), and e* is also in MST(G). So I was wondering if you could make a statement similar for all e in MST(G)

Also I think you mean minimUM spanning tree everywhere.

There is probably no good algorithms for this. The reason I think this (in my naive opinion) is because $k$-MST is hard, but if we can solve this, we can effectively solve $k$-MST. Just use $v$ as a budget and do a binary search. It would take time some $O(\log W)$ where $W$ is the sum of the edge weights. This is not really polynomial time, but you can probably start to see the issues.

@HackR k-MST is hard, but it's not necessary to find a k-MST here. Just a spanning tree with sufficiently low cost. Or am I missing something?

@Qise I am going the other way. If you can solve this, then with at most $O(\log(W)$ overhead, you can solve $k$-MST. Granted this is not a polytime reduction, but it's something that came to mind regarding how hard this might be.

@HackR since every edge weight is a part of input, $\log W$ is upper bounded by the information quantity of the input (the input size), and the reduction is polynomial

If you still have some doubts about non-integer weights, I should mention that there is no polynomial time $96/95$-approximation scheme for $k$-MST (unless $\mathrm P = NP$)

@Smylic Ah I see what you mean. It's the log factor that saves the reduction. I also had the knapsack in mind, but there's it's a linear factor of $W$, not a logarithmic factor. Thanks for pointing this out.

@HackR binary search gives logarithmic factor

@Smylic Yes, and I mentioned as much. But i missed the interpretation that the log factor gives the number of bits, not just the numerical value :p

@HackR it gives a polynomial reduction from $k$-MST to the given problem.

As it was pointed in the comments your problem is equivalent to $k$-MST for $k = m$. This problem is known to be $\mathrm{NP}$-hard. On the other hand, there is a polynomial $2$-approximation scheme, which may solve your problem when bound $v$ is not too tight. I. e., if there exist a solution with bound $v/2$, then we can find a solution with bound $v$ in polynomial time.
